# How can I have a form where the text in the input remains when it's been clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I was practicing PHP. I'm a learner. I'm just trying to find out how to make the info left in the input remain there when clicked, for special purposes. I tried using jquery to make that possible but it's not working.

Here's my html

```
<form method="post">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit now" id="submission" name="submit_now" />
</form>
```

Here's my PHP

```
<code>

<?php
      $Admin = array("Eric", "Emeka", "Faith", "Lucy", "Theressa", "Hillary", "Justice", "Kate", "Rob");
      $Users = array("Jonah", "Augustar", "Orma", "Edwin", "Kirk Franklin", "Michael Jackson", "Hopsin", "Nike");
      $blacklist = array("Kenny", "kenny");
      $key = 1;

      if ($_POST["submit_now"]){
      if($_POST["name"]){
      foreach($Admin as $val){
      if ($_POST["name"]==$val){
      echo "I know you ".$_POST["name"]." You're actually an Admin and have an awesome place in your own life or someone else's life";

      $key = 1;
    }
  }
  foreach($Users as $vall){
    if ($_POST["name"]==$vall){
      echo "I know you".$_POST["name"];
      $key = 2;
    }
  }
  foreach($blacklist as $valll){
    if ($_POST["name"]==$valll){
      echo "You've been banished ".$_POST["name"]." Leave and never return!";
      $key = 3;
    }
  }
  if ($key!=1 AND $key!=2 AND $key!=3){
    echo "<b style=\"color:red\">Sorry I don't know you...";
  }
}
 }

 ?>
```

And there's my jQuery

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submission").click(function(){
    $("#name").val();
    var a = $("#name").val();
    $("#name").attr("val", "a");
  });

})
  </script>
```

Please just let me know where I went wrong

Comment: Where you post you form?

Comment: Use `AJAX` to post data instead or regular submit. This is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: Check my answer and let me know is that what your want.

Comment: I posted from Nigeria Nikhil Vaghla

Comment: Worked smoothly Shrikant...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want keep value entered in the input box after form submit, you can try like this

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the value part like:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php echo $name1; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you use `AJAX` (submission without the browser reloading the page) and you can set something like

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return false;" .. />
```

so that the submission is not processed, and then capture the `click` event of the button you want to let the user submit, and send the data with `jQuery.ajax()`

OR

You use standard PHP and when you return the `HTML` from the server include something like:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>" />
```

and your page will be reloaded with the value the user submitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fredster...I'll note that...I was practicing with wampserver so I'm virtually returning html to the page when the button is clicked. I just went straight to Shrikant's answer first from the comment section....

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form attribut action='' for same page post or any other page link

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <input name="name" type="text" id="" placeholder="First Name" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit now" id="submission" name="submit_now" />
</form>
```